# Websocket interceptor

Tags: nginx, websocket, lua, openresty

I'm looking for a way to wrap/intercept a websocket with a proxy that enriches the responses coming back from the web socket, as implicitly as possible.

For example, lets say I have a websocket endpoint: wss://stream.abc.com:1234 and I want to enrich the incoming json messages.

A brute force approach would create a new endpoint that's listening and creating a web socket to the remote socket for every connection and proxying the communication enriching the responses before sending them back to the client.

However I wonder if there's a more standard library that can do that, maybe with nginx?

Thanks,
Z